# Shemona Ushloshim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred thirty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gematria, again - 238 is `רחל` (Rachel), Yaakov's wife.
Interestingly, I checked and it is also `אהבה טהורה` (pure love), which plays nicely with Yaakov's relationship with Rachel... (though I admit I dont hold much weight to arbitrary gematrisizings, to easy to turn this to anything else...)